# How do I scale a websocket server?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I'm creating a websocket chat app, and I'm thinking about making it scale.

The class I'm using is: 
`org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session`

Right now, I keep a `Set<Session>` in memory, but what would be the best way to make this scale? Since different clients could potentially connect to different servers, wouldn't all the backend servers need to keep a collection of all the connections, and thus need to persist every session and replicate it across all my backend servers in order to make sure that every client receives a broadcast?

If server A only knows about chatter tim, then it wouldn't be able to broadcast messages to the other users.

On the other hand, persisting sessions seems wrong since a shared connection pool could grow very large, and persisting them and reloading them could be complicated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual scheme is that you store session info in a database that all your servers can read from.  Then, when you want to send a message to any given user, you can consult the database to find which server it is connected to (some of this info can be effectively cached locally on each server too).